# How do I extract the values in a matrix with same first 7 characters in row and column name

Tags: r

Assuming I have multiple rectangles with one point on each corner and I have created a matrix for distance from all the points to all other points. However, I only need distance points in each rectangle. For example, only when the first 7 characters of the row and column are same. That should give me 6 unique values (considering no two points are on same distance from each other)
I have added a picture to understand the structure
[image]

Here is a small sample data

```r
structure(c(0, 364.930299211309, 604.442307105484, 410.991769186984, 
16790.711415192, 16855.1485866349, 364.930299211309, 0, 366.000060144176, 
551.439334796924, 16578.9485598795, 16644.4631060393, 604.442307105484, 
366.000060144176, 0, 507.181333592942, 16223.1121382276, 16288.3157507677, 
410.991769186984, 551.439334796924, 507.181333592942, 0, 16461.5424525418, 
16525.072234626, 16790.711415192, 16578.9485598795, 16223.1121382276, 
16461.5424525418, 0, 88.797749793446, 16855.1485866349, 16644.4631060393, 
16288.3157507677, 16525.072234626, 88.797749793446, 0, 16780.7325183588, 
16569.9453695848, 16213.8248878271, 16450.7578628425, 55.5123088437835, 
74.6879092649611, 16685.4461612851, 16474.3661467207, 16118.3271996141, 
16355.736578168, 111.65891296113, 171.334534364881, 8278.91449042027, 
8307.97025914842, 8660.79734335381, 8689.09430512198, 24176.4642838139, 
24251.0451886659, 8291.2167120843, 8310.57629472996, 8660.74801095243, 
8701.92923897152, 24103.2381070123, 24178.2321727744, 8194.37525889284, 
8213.53053663935, 8563.67862136739, 8605.09994070435, 24011.5124211919, 
24086.4438705306, 8139.1222615634, 8166.56413601811, 8519.01225073755, 
8549.41961746109, 24032.0737743933, 24106.6227859227, 116835.831624242, 
117151.592151693, 117098.246896166, 116627.69115306, 119717.328274311, 
119673.340153011, 116894.895528406, 117210.612188378, 117157.179801737, 
116686.669781877, 119771.907758699, 119727.896450559, 116981.185319202, 
117296.894383494, 117243.446367649, 116772.944642533, 119856.686781357, 
119812.664655996, 116905.156839711, 117220.925401085, 117167.595530678, 
116697.031812041, 119786.70021518, 119742.709163057, 137548.21551912, 
137869.911212853, 137828.552342883, 137352.012529264, 140804.647343423, 
140761.585805883, 137432.061451682, 137753.756916661, 137712.398160743, 
137235.85819163, 140689.277368248, 140646.223285041, 137335.716364217, 
137657.466801762, 137616.224486427, 137139.628763376, 140598.794003302, 
140555.770271277, 137450.620031593, 137772.369381656, 137731.124181241, 
137254.52993692, 140712.796932126, 140669.765239517, 308493.270889503, 
308238.693560841, 307900.923543467, 308200.975526817, 291887.614524464, 
291833.363916705, 308450.712928682, 308196.116928348, 307858.356983648, 
308158.438236869, 291845.240657898, 291790.995444887, 308417.890950377, 
308163.241595123, 307825.510454734, 308125.67526815, 291812.941943133, 
291758.711960823, 308442.306574476, 308187.612662545, 307849.905596447, 
308150.140146077, 291837.793215765, 291783.575846376, 304625.431712835, 
304395.599949664, 304046.435165169, 304308.153381379, 287860.431950347, 
287799.701040423, 304673.973526676, 304444.182131566, 304095.001715416, 
304356.657954127, 287908.837619173, 287848.096909704, 304822.432549619, 
304592.531454456, 304243.393566859, 304505.217989528, 288057.665696087, 
287996.951387891, 304863.043676073, 304633.15006293, 304284.009277822, 
304545.822185079, 288098.251238621, 288037.535086693, 304229.780232868, 
304018.12715714, 303662.778058715, 303896.781648811, 287439.750549196, 
287374.866196844, 304282.703320851, 304070.974937302, 303715.648082599, 
303949.765749462, 287492.634791487, 287427.766691918, 304290.887730087, 
304079.081548834, 303723.77769689, 303958.013255205, 287500.780255042, 
287435.928954353, 304246.05266861, 304034.150823593, 303678.875290813, 
303913.255866132, 287455.898956235, 287391.068324819, 149662.503948563, 
150011.728802967, 150042.307396971, 149540.990756408, 155962.780991847, 
155934.403757724, 149596.404612597, 149945.651129832, 149976.304508479, 
149474.972051766, 155900.141423918, 155871.78427269, 149563.291094581, 
149912.570596444, 149943.337681537, 149441.981250351, 155871.951279968, 
155843.621025952, 149617.906412949, 149967.168569913, 149997.875706539, 
149496.531927463, 155923.785329008, 155895.438885628, 109612.07253716, 
109915.504641077, 109839.223819728, 109381.688022902, 111519.395232088, 
111471.383345024, 294780.162151632, 294555.319300683, 294204.28748574, 
294458.373700857, 278001.210293242, 277939.298074975, 109537.373980891, 
109840.68990978, 109764.204901048, 109306.79423011, 111436.077646899, 
111388.031630041, 109617.459258599, 109920.633554169, 109843.89845903, 
109386.641481509, 111503.738623932, 111455.633867881, 294881.360522429, 
294656.616853575, 294305.549293018, 294559.483787008, 278102.186243936, 
278040.250684806, 109734.110651157, 110037.441344702, 109960.980718578, 
109503.555333472, 111631.804537271, 111583.744066489, 294671.287225042, 
294446.632888291, 294095.533143134, 294349.331266577, 277891.91550314, 
277829.959124555, 294735.945339949, 294511.393087673, 294160.256648029, 
294413.898667183, 277956.349111251, 277894.368762537, 520265.01212354, 
519900.112715735, 519770.092670342, 520273.255807048, 510762.350605606, 
510777.60202084, 519731.632568247, 519366.72990619, 519236.468890384, 
519739.587060819, 510219.328302977, 510234.519452567, 520067.352872377, 
519702.455109509, 519572.552157942, 520075.737072445, 510569.538406276, 
510584.821179342, 519743.107039358, 519378.208494155, 519248.250320994, 
519751.424992716, 510243.15356859, 510258.423458149, 521650.938282182, 
521286.200804094, 521162.878556497, 521667.188301624, 512421.832315294, 
512438.809791122, 522027.323761335, 521662.567899423, 521538.698011763, 
522042.921462464, 512775.617437653, 512792.452290484, 522404.680017575, 
522039.930356359, 521916.248123095, 522420.501272295, 513160.535777932, 
513177.41720843, 522424.649735685, 522059.910717759, 521936.54345096, 
522440.846122743, 513193.419686588, 513210.382054801, 277398.710410213, 
277125.253615472, 277250.157847496, 277672.943023385, 279497.363373899, 
279567.789497135, 276810.260205618, 276536.723616141, 276661.514963087, 
277084.391876995, 278904.477073317, 278974.892294319, 276708.118962939, 
276434.375356784, 276558.871705227, 276981.988256785, 278788.29896639, 
278858.669417802, 276870.904553846, 276597.07382995, 276721.445651372, 
277144.663269572, 278944.808135859, 279015.15733577, 275201.156925613, 
274920.137862327, 275034.014639639, 275465.504722393, 276774.039265969, 
276842.748783494, 275090.125964583, 274808.838162688, 274922.313104215, 
275354.110453953, 276643.971671941, 276712.618057966, 274915.280929442, 
274634.262664382, 274748.141016786, 275179.62985262, 276488.737999414, 
276557.451210162, 274919.615413661, 274638.965742297, 274753.39427793, 
275184.461266036, 276519.402028069, 276588.20333444, 272393.859577198, 
272115.212288446, 272232.610058647, 272661.377616142, 274140.374430648, 
274209.679433557, 272823.499297937, 272544.721570946, 272661.926731667, 
273090.844638155, 274560.015743794, 274629.284987979, 272863.557367621, 
272585.37965681, 272703.466742037, 273131.695190808, 274642.305122298, 
274711.71374702, 272390.614727683, 272112.552780692, 272230.810281142, 
272658.90505137, 274178.376804486, 274247.818101383, 21368.3284627434, 
21307.3663113006, 21622.8598992783, 21773.5335591509, 35161.0534392998, 
35245.695275641, 21443.5474321524, 21382.8039112002, 21698.4012300959, 
21848.7953938805, 35236.3746407676, 35321.0263871004, 21438.6645227168, 
21377.014257332, 21692.1468005365, 21843.7403892556, 35213.2353239803, 
35297.9242851801, 21384.8866172282, 21322.72257453, 21637.5964385716, 
21789.8626979581, 35152.0693816675, 35236.766365204), dim = c(6L, 
68L), dimnames = list(c("BYWR110A", "BYWR110B", "BYWR110C", "BYWR110D", 
"BYWR111A", "BYWR111B"), c("BYWR110A", "BYWR110B", "BYWR110C", 
"BYWR110D", "BYWR111A", "BYWR111B", "BYWR111C", "BYWR111D", "BYWR112D", 
"BYWR112C", "BYWR112B", "BYWR112A", "BWWR101A", "BWWR101C", "BWWR101B", 
"BWWR101D", "BWWR100A", "BWWR100B", "BWWR100C", "BWWR100D", "NWWR130A", 
"NWWR130B", "NWWR130C", "NWWR130D", "NWWR131A", "NWWR131B", "NWWR131C", 
"NWWR131D", "NWWR132A", "NWWR132B", "NWWR132C", "NWWR132D", "BWWR103A", 
"BWWR103B", "BWWR103C", "BWWR103D", "BWWR102A", "NWWR133B", "BWWR102D", 
"BWWR102C", "NWWR133A", "BWWR102B", "NWWR133C", "NWWR133D", "MVWR170-A", 
"MVWR170-B", "MVWR170-C", "MVWR170-D", "MVWR171-A", "MVWR171-B", 
"MVWR171-C", "MVWR171-D", "SNWR140a_SF", "SNWR140b", "SNWR140c", 
"SNWR140d", "SNWR141a", "SNWR141b", "SNWR141c", "SNWR141d_SF", 
"SNWR142a_SF", "SNWR142b", "SNWR142c", "SNWR142d", "BYWR113A", 
"BYWR113B", "BYWR113C", "BYWR113D")), units = structure(list(
    numerator = "m", denominator = character(0)), class = "symbolic_units"), class = "units")
```

The code I have been trying

```
d <- as.data.frame.table(mre)
d <- transform(d, Freq = as.numeric(Freq))
out <- subset(d, Var1 == sub("\\d{7,}", "", Var2),
              select =c(Var1, Var2, Freq))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting the values from the whole data frame into a list of data frames. Assuming 4 letters and 3 digits, based on the example.

```
sapply(unique(sub("([[:alpha:]]{4}\\d{3}).*", "\\1", colnames(df))), function(x) 
  df[grepl(x, rownames(df)), grepl(x, colnames(df))])
$BYWR110
         BYWR110A BYWR110B BYWR110C BYWR110D
BYWR110A   0.0000 364.9303 604.4423 410.9918
BYWR110B 364.9303   0.0000 366.0001 551.4393
BYWR110C 604.4423 366.0001   0.0000 507.1813
BYWR110D 410.9918 551.4393 507.1813   0.0000

$BYWR111
         BYWR111A BYWR111B BYWR111C BYWR111D
BYWR111A  0.00000 88.79775 55.51231 111.6589
BYWR111B 88.79775  0.00000 74.68791 171.3345

$BYWR112
     BYWR112D BYWR112C BYWR112B BYWR112A

$BWWR101
     BWWR101A BWWR101C BWWR101B BWWR101D
...
```

If you only wanted the unique vector

```
sapply(unique(sub("([[:alpha:]]{4}\\d{3}).*", "\\1", colnames(df))), function(x){
  res <- df[grepl(x, rownames(df)), grepl(x, colnames(df))]
  res[upper.tri(res)]})
$BYWR110
[1] 364.9303 604.4423 366.0001 410.9918 551.4393 507.1813

$BYWR111
[1]  88.79775  55.51231  74.68791 111.65891 171.33453

$BYWR112
numeric(0)

$BWWR101
numeric(0)
...
```

Comment: Thanks, the second one does exactly what I have been trying to do since last 2 days

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substr()` to split the names of the points into the names of the rectangle and the ids of the corners. Then you can filter in `subset()` for those distances belonging to the same rectangle, sorted by the corner IDs to avoid duplicates:

```
d$Rectangle <- substr(d$Var1, 1, 7)
d$Rectangle2 <- substr(d$Var2, 1, 7)
d$corner <- substr(d$Var1, 8, 8)
d$corner2 <- substr(d$Var2, 8, 8)

out <- subset(d, Rectangle == Rectangle2 & corner < corner2,
              select =c(Rectangle, Var1, Var2, Freq))

out
#    Rectangle     Var1     Var2      Freq
# 7    BYWR110 BYWR110A BYWR110B 364.93030
# 13   BYWR110 BYWR110A BYWR110C 604.44231
# 14   BYWR110 BYWR110B BYWR110C 366.00006
# 19   BYWR110 BYWR110A BYWR110D 410.99177
# 20   BYWR110 BYWR110B BYWR110D 551.43933
# 21   BYWR110 BYWR110C BYWR110D 507.18133
# 35   BYWR111 BYWR111A BYWR111B  88.79775
# 41   BYWR111 BYWR111A BYWR111C  55.51231
# 42   BYWR111 BYWR111B BYWR111C  74.68791
# 47   BYWR111 BYWR111A BYWR111D 111.65891
# 48   BYWR111 BYWR111B BYWR111D 171.33453
```